# Load binding redirects from *.dll.config when loading an assembly dynamically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing a windows service that is dynamically loading an DLL which contains the actual logic for that service. It is loaded using `Assembly.LoadFrom(...)`. That assembly is referencing `Microsoft.Graph` on NuGet which in turn requires some other libraries, `System.ValueTuple` in particular. When compiling the versions are resolved properly, but when loading the assembly it tries to find version 4.0.1.0 when 4.0.2.0 is present.

So I created a binding redirect like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I enabled FusionLog and it told me it wasn't even loading this file (I put it next to the DLL with the name .dll.config). How can I use those binding redirects in connection with `Assembly.LoadFrom()`?

The fusion log (sorry it's german):

```
*** Protokolleintrag für Assembly-Binder  (06.08.2019 @ 09:14:03) ***

Fehler bei diesem Vorgang.
Ergebnis der Bindung: hr = 0x80070002. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

Der Assemblymanager wurde geladen aus:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Als EXE-Datei ausgeführt.  C:\Program Files (x86)\iSM\biCube\services\BiCube.Services.Host.exe
--- Ein detailliertes Fehlerprotokoll folgt. 

=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/iSM/biCube/services/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: DynamicBase = NULL
LOG: CacheBase = NULL
LOG: AppName = BiCube.Services.Host.exe
Aufruf von Assembly : Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=1.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
LOG: Es wurde keine Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei gefunden.
LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: 
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: Die Suche im GAC war nicht erfolgreich.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/iSM/biCube/services/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/iSM/biCube/services/System.ValueTuple/System.ValueTuple.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/iSM/biCube/services/System.ValueTuple.EXE.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/iSM/biCube/services/System.ValueTuple/System.ValueTuple.EXE.
LOG: Fehler bei allen Such-URLs.
```

Comment: In which assembly have you defined binding redirect?

Comment: The assembly that is getting called using Assembly.LoadFrom(). It contains the logic and is also written by me. The name is not important here.

Comment: The assembly that is being loaded is referencing the Microsoft.Graph, which is in turn failing to load the System.ValueTuple.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the entry -
`<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />`
As per that only versions 0 to 4.0.1 will be redirected to 4.0.2.
You should keep the `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0"`